# How to make a grid of buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

I'm learning Java these days, my first project is to create a "Go board", 9 * 9 rows and columns, and place black and white stones on the intersections.

I created a board with 9 * 9 lines and columns, now I have to create black and white stones using the `JButton` component.

Other than the color, size, and position of the button on the first row (`setLayout`), I was unable to turn the button into a circle and place the stone on the intersection points.

From multiple searches for related guides, I have noticed that there is some unique structure that I am not familiar with for creating and designing buttons.

And now my question comes in - what is the code structure I need to create in order to produce a button in the shape of a circle, size 65 * 65, in black or white? Do I need to create a new class for this? How and where should I integrate `JPanel`?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board(900, 900, "Go board");
    }
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private String title;

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Board(int width, int height, String title) {
        super();
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.title = title;
        this.initBoard();

    }

    public Board() {
        super();
    }

    public void initBoard() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(this.getTitle());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(25, 75, 47));
        f.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        // f.setLocation(550, 25);
        f.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);

        JButton stone = new JButton("    ");
        f.add(stone);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        stone.setBackground(Color.BLACK.darker());
        stone.setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(getForeground()));
        stone.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 65));

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, 10 + (i * ((this.getWidth() - 20) / 9)), this.getWidth(),
                    10 + (i * ((this.getWidth() - 20) / 9)));
            g.drawLine(10 + (i * ((this.getHeight() - 20) / 9)), 0, 10 + (i * ((this.getHeight() - 20) / 9)),
                    this.getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Before uploading the post, I read the following posts:

- [Design Button in Java (like in CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698092/design-button-in-java-like-in-css)
- [How can I set size of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536873/how-can-i-set-size-of-a-button/2537024)
- [Java: JButton with custom Shape: Fill with Metal Look and Feel Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274890/java-jbutton-with-custom-shape-fill-with-metal-look-and-feel-gradient)
- [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)
- [Java JButton](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jbutton)
- [How to use `setUI` method in `javax.swing.JButton`](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/javax.swing.JButton/setUI)

Note: I do not want to access posts that explain how to produce a "Go board", the learning process in this context is my goal.

Comment: Generally, you create a logical model of a Go board using a plain Java getter / setter class.  You use a drawing JPanel to create the Go board in the GUI and draw circles to represent the stones.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), will show you the steps to creating a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: Creating a board of circles using custom painting (overriding `paintComponent`) is one way to go. Building the board using `JButton`s (or `JLable`s) , typically place using `GridLayout` is a different one (See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191460/3992939))

Comment: *"what is the code structure I need to create in order to produce a button in the shape of a circle, size 65 * 65, in black or white?"* I'd instead use a square button formed using a circular image, with the button decorations & margin removed. For the removed parts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556). The grid of the Go board would consist of 9 other different icons. 4 x `T` shapes in each direction, 4 x corner icons, and a `+` icon for all the rest of the buttons. So ultimately it would be a 9x9 grid layout of buttons, adjusted to look like the model describe by..

Comment: .. @GilbertLeBlanc in the first comment. *"Do I need to create a new class for this?"* No. A plain old Java `JButton` will do, it just needs to be adjusted to need (using its existing methods). *"How and where should I integrate `JPanel`?"* What? I'm not sure I understand that, but the game board would be a (again standard) `JPanel` with a 9 x 9 `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you skipped over some of the important parts of the Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Here's my comment from August 23rd, just 10 days ago.

> Generally, you create a logical model of a Go board using a plain Java
> getter / setter class. You use a drawing `JPanel` to create the Go board
> in the GUI and draw circles to represent the stones. The Oracle
> tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), will show you the steps to
> creating a Swing GUI. Skip the Netbeans section.

So, where's your logical model?  Where's your drawing `JPanel`?

Here's a quick GUI I created.

[image: Go Board]

My code has a logical model.  My code has a drawing `JPanel`.

The first thing I did was create a plain Java getter / setter class to hold a logical representation of a Go Board.  I named this the `Board` class.

The next thing I did was start my Swing GUI with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I used the `run` method of my `Runnable` class to create the `JFrame`.  The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for all my Swing applications.

I separate the creation of the `JFrame` from the creation of any subsequent `JPanels`.  I do this to keep my code organized, easy to read, and easy to understand.

I extend a `JPanel` to create the drawing `JPanel`.  I do this so I can override the `paintComponent` method of the `JPanel` class.  The drawing `JPanel` draws (paints) the board state.  That's all.  Nothing else.  Another class will take care of adding pieces to the logical Go board and repainting the drawing JPanel.

The `MoveListener` class implements a `MouseListener` (extends a `MouseAdapter`) to respond to mouse clicks on the Go board.  The `MoveListener` class keeps track of whose turn it is.  In a more elaborate version of a Go board, you would have another plain Java getter / setter class to keep track of the game state.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GoBoard implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GoBoard());
    }
    
    private Board board;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public GoBoard() {
        this.board = new Board();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Go Board");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(board);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private final int margin, pieceRadius, lineSpacing;
        
        private Board board;
        
        public DrawingPanel(Board board) {
            this.board = board;
            
            this.margin = 60;
            this.pieceRadius = 40;
            this.lineSpacing = 100;
            this.setBackground(new Color(0x993300));
            int width = 8 * lineSpacing + margin + margin;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, width));
            this.addMouseListener(new MoveListener(board));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            paintHorizontalLines(g2d);
            paintVerticalLines(g2d);
            paintPieces(g2d);
        }
        
        private void paintHorizontalLines(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int x = margin;
            int y1 = margin;
            int y2 = getHeight() - margin;
            
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
            for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                g2d.drawLine(x, y1, x, y2);
                x += lineSpacing;
            }
        }
        
        private void paintVerticalLines(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int x1 = margin;
            int x2 = getWidth() - margin;
            int y = margin;
            
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
            for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                g2d.drawLine(x1, y, x2, y);
                y += lineSpacing;
            }
        }
        
        private void paintPieces(Graphics2D g2d) {
            int[][] b = board.getBoard();
            for (int row = 0; row < b.length; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < b[row].length; column++) {
                    int x = column * lineSpacing + margin;
                    int y = row * lineSpacing + margin;
                    if (b[row][column] == 1) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g2d.fillOval(x - pieceRadius, y - pieceRadius, 
                                pieceRadius + pieceRadius, pieceRadius + pieceRadius);
                    } else if (b[row][column] == 2) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2d.fillOval(x - pieceRadius, y - pieceRadius, 
                                pieceRadius + pieceRadius, pieceRadius + pieceRadius);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class MoveListener extends MouseAdapter {
        
        private boolean isBlackTurn = true;
        
        private Board board;
        
        public MoveListener(Board board) {
            this.board = board;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            Point point = event.getPoint();
            int margin = 60;
            int pieceRadius = 40;
            int lineSpacing = 100;
            int column = (point.x - margin + pieceRadius) / lineSpacing;
            int row = (point.y - margin + pieceRadius) / lineSpacing;
            int piece = (isBlackTurn) ? 1 : 2;
            board.setPiece(piece, row, column);
            drawingPanel.repaint();
            isBlackTurn = !isBlackTurn;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Board {
        
        private int[][] board;
        
        public Board() {
            this.board = new int[9][9];
        }
        
        /**
         * <p>
         * This method inserts a piece on the board.
         * </p>
         * 
         * @param piece  - 1 for black, 2 for white
         * @param row    - row of piece
         * @param column - column of piece
         */
        public void setPiece(int piece, int row, int column) {
            this.board[row][column] = piece;
        }

        public int[][] getBoard() {
            return board;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JPanel` with a 9x9 `GridLayout` and ad to it `JButtons` configured to your need as demonstrated in the following very basic [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridOfButtons extends JPanel {

    private static final int ROWS = 9, COLS = 9, SIZE = 65, BORDER = 2;
    private static final Color BOARD_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    public GridOfButtons() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, BORDER, BORDER));
        setBackground(BOARD_COLOR);

        StonesFactory factory = new StonesFactory(SIZE);
        boolean isBlack = false;

        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                add(factory.makeButton(isBlack));
                isBlack = !isBlack;
            }
        }

        this.initBoard();
    }

    public void initBoard() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Board Of Buttons");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new GridOfButtons());
    }
}

class StonesFactory{

    private static final Color STONE = Color.YELLOW, WHITE_STONE = Color.WHITE, BLACK_STONE = Color.BLACK;
    private final int size;
    private final ImageIcon whiteIcon, blackIcon;

    public StonesFactory(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        whiteIcon = new ImageIcon(createImage(false));
        blackIcon = new ImageIcon(createImage(true));
    }

    JButton makeButton(boolean isBlack){
        JButton stone = new JButton();
        stone.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        stone.setBackground(STONE);
        stone.setIcon(isBlack ? blackIcon : whiteIcon);
        return stone;
    }

    //construct image for button's icon
    private BufferedImage createImage(boolean isBlack) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(size , size,  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(isBlack ? BLACK_STONE : WHITE_STONE);
        g2.fillOval(0,0,size,size);
        g2.dispose();
        return img;
    }
}
```

(Run it [online](https://replit.com/@c0derrepo/GridOfButtons#Main.java))

---

[image]

---

---

Alternatively you can produce the board by custom painting of a `JPanel`. This will make the individual "stones" not clickable and more difficult to modify:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridByPainting extends JPanel {

    private static final int ROWS = 9, COLS = 9, SIZE = 65, BORDER = 2;
    private static final Color BOARD_COLOR = Color.BLACK, STONE = Color.YELLOW,
            WHITE_STONE = Color.WHITE, BLACK_STONE = Color.BLACK;
    private final Dimension size;

    public GridByPainting() {
        int x = BORDER + COLS*(SIZE + BORDER);
        int y = BORDER + ROWS*(SIZE + BORDER);
        size = new Dimension(x,y);
        this.initBoard();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void initBoard() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Grid By Painting");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth(); int height = getHeight();
        int stoneWidth = (width - BORDER) / COLS  - BORDER;
        int stoneHeight = (height -BORDER)/ ROWS - BORDER ;

        //draw board
        g.setColor(BOARD_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        boolean isBlack = true;
        //draw square stones
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                int x = BORDER + col*(stoneWidth + BORDER);
                int y = BORDER + row*(stoneHeight + BORDER);
                g.setColor(STONE);
                g.fillRect(x, y, stoneWidth, stoneHeight);
                //draw circle
                g.setColor(isBlack ? BLACK_STONE : WHITE_STONE);
                isBlack = !isBlack;
                g.fillOval(x, y, stoneWidth, stoneHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new GridByPainting());
    }
}
```

(Run it [online](https://replit.com/@c0derrepo/GridByPainting#Main.java))

---

[image]